# Override right margin property in PhpStorm on the fly / per file

Tags: phpstorm

Jetbrain's PhpStorm has an option to set the right margin in the editor (eg. 80 or 120 characters). The option is for example used for the automatic code reformatting.

I would like to override this setting with a higher value or deactivate it completely for some files (containing translations). These files are php files as well, so a 'per file type' solution does not work.

**Is there a way to achieve this in PhpStorm?**

Maybe a 'per folder' solution or something like the inspection options, written directly into the files e.g.:

```
/** @noinspection PhpUnusedParameterInspection */
```

Comment: AFAIK there is no such option in IDE settings to be it dynamic like that. And it's definitely will not be supported by such Doc comments. `.editorconfig` file has [max_line_length](https://github.com/editorconfig/editorconfig/wiki/EditorConfig-Properties#max_line_length) property .. but it does not seem to be supported by EditorConfig plugin that PhpStorm uses (based on the info from that link -- did not do actual tests).

Comment: If the code reformatting at hard character cap (80) is breaking your code, then you need to review it, something is wrong. You should follow the PSR.

Comment: @leo_ap It's not breaking anything but it's still confusing to edit a language file with lot's of breaks in it. In this use case 'neatly arranged' beats the otherwise rational limit as it is no classic code file.

Comment: @mvo understood

Answer (score 0):

To skip the automatic code formatting for specific regions on files, use the `Formatter Control` options under: `Settings->Editor->Code Style`. 
See: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/2016.2/reformatting-source-code.html#d919037e110 for examples of use.

Also, turn off the option: `Wrap on Typing`, on the same place specified above.

Comment: Of course I just can't run code formatting, but beeing able to use code formatting for space adjustments [...] was kind of the idea that lead to my question. :-)

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the Formatter Control options, though.

Comment: @mvo I edited my answer as it seems to be what you need.

Comment: That would only help if I would not like to use the formatter at all for those files. (If that would be the case deactivating it would allow to format the whole solution but wouldn't solve the problem in the first place)

Comment: well, in your question you said that "Maybe [..] written directly into the files [...]". and then you gave an example with a comment doc. I thought it would be your solution